# Getting PartCover.Browser.exe to show a coverage xml through command line

Tags: partcover

Need help with a silly question. How do I get PartCover.Browser.exe to load and show an existing coverage xml generated by PartCover.exe?

I have a batch file that runs PartCover.exe and my tests and generates the coverage xml without problems. Then I try to load the xml with PartCover.Browser.exe.

```
"C:\Program Files\PartCover .NET 2\PartCover.Browser.exe" "D:\coverage.xml"
```

but that doesn't seem to work. Is it even supported? Can't seem to find any documentation on it either. I'm using PartCover 2.2.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did some more digging on my own and saw that it's not supported yet but in the list of [feature requests](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=2445978&group_id=175733&atid=874421).

Answer (score 0):

From looking at the code:
[partcover-fork](http://wiki.github.com/geofflane/partcover-fork/) can do this.